# Dynamically Add textview in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to add textview dynamically in alertdialog. But  end up with null pointer error.
My code...

```
att_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.att_layout);


 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Consultation.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            TextView con = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
            con.setText("Consultation on " + item.getString(4));
            TextView des = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
            des.setText(item.getString(2));
            TextView pre = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView31);
            pre.setText(item.getString(3));
            TextView fee = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView32);
            fee.setText(item.getString(5));
            if (att.getCount() == 0) {
                att.close();
            } else {

//here is the part where error occurs
                View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.att_values, null);
                TextView att_name=(TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
                att_name.setText(att.getString(3));
                TextView att_value=(TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
                att_value.setText(att.getString(4));
                att_layout.addView(addView);

            }
            adapter1 = new GridViewAdapter(FilePathStrings, getApplicationContext());
            grid = (GridView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter1);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + FilePathStrings[position]), "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

alert_label_editor.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView27"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView28"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Prescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView30"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView31"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="fee"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView33"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView32"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/att_layout"></LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</LinearLayout>
```

att_values.xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView34"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

When i add those dynamically adding code.. its stops worling... The whole other code is working fine...

Logcat...

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
```

How can i resolve this issue.?

Comment: Looks like `R.id.att_layout` is not part of the view of this `Activity`. Can you share your layout xml file?

Comment: i ve added the xml codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alert_label_editor.xml` file which contains the `R.id.att_layout` LinearLayout is not inflated until you run this line:

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
```

So when you try to find it in the current view, it is not found and `att_layout` is `null`

Move this line after you actually inflate the layout, and use `dialogView`:

```
att_layout = (LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.att_layout);
```